# iOS: creating a Server in Objective-C for iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webserver

experts and friends. I have a question regarding creating a server for iPhone app. I have had experiences with HTML, server-side stuffs such as using PHP, mySQL etc. 
But making an App utilizing a server is something I have not experienced with.

The ideas is as follows:

1.) A simple server that sends out responses in JSON format (I have only had experiences with parsing in Objective-C but not generating from within a server).

2.) Enabling users to create a very simple account (profile name, password, a 50 x 50 px profile picture)

3.) It is just a fun / learning project between me and my other coworker. We were hoping to do, let's say, if I am driving to work and so does he, on the same route, we were hoping to be able to see each other's locations on google map and send each other /receive message each other a short message via the server.

And we were hoping to do all this server stuffs (preferably) within xCode and in Objective-C. There are many resources for server-side stuffs on the web for Java, Python, PHP etc, but not Objective-C. And we would love to be able to do all these in Objective-C.

I was hoping to get some advice regarding the technologies needed (ex: from hardware to software requirements to the structure / architecture of the set up)
from all of you.  Sample code and description would also be helpful.

Note: we are knowledgeable on how server works (sending / receiving requests, etc) and have coded already in Objective-C.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is much too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I am driving to work and so does he, on the same route, we were hoping to be able to see each other's locations on google map and send each other /receive message each other a short message via the server.

Your IP address will likely often change, so if you want your server to be always available, it will have to periodically update some database in a fixed location (e.g. dynamic DNS resolver).

However, note that Apple makes it possible for your app to stay in the background and receive location updates, but does not allow you to accept incoming network connections in the background.

The correct way to send a message to a constantly moving iOS device is through Apple's push services, as in this case Apple takes care of maintaining connection with the device.

So the best way to implement your app is still to go with classic **client-server architecture**:

- server in a fixed location
- if you want to send a message to the device, server sends a push notification through Apple's server
- your app registers to receive push notifications so it's able to display them anywhere.

As for location, depending on whether you want your friend to be able to see you at all times, or only with your permission, you can either

- register your app to wake up when location changes significantly to notify server about its location OR
- implement a push notification *my friend wants to see your location!* and give the user the ability to send or decline sending the location.

If you're not sure about implementing servers and push services, Apple makes it relatively easy, as you can buy $500 Mac mini and install $20 OS X Server to get some pre-implemented functionality.